# Django models saves database entries starting with id 2 (not id1)

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-models

Following is my model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.post_title)
```

Following is my query

```
def posts(request, pk):
    post_list = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'testing/posts.html', {'post_list': post_list} )
```

I have checked the database entry - it starts with id-2. Also, the URL with id-1 isn't working. ***Note: I am using MySQL database***

Why does it happen?

Comment: You might have deleted the entry with id 1?...

Comment: Try to truncate the table and then try again

Comment: Also if an insertion fails, the id will be blocked and next one is used